# Why do my old Povray files not work in a new installation?

Tags: povray

I have just installed Povray on a new computer. Suddenly, files that have always worked before produce weird errors.

[`6.pov`](https://github.com/watchduck/convex_polyhedra/blob/master/2b_colors_png/finished_pov/8/6.pov) should render [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Polyhedron_6.png) image of a cube. But apparently the `#for` gets confused for a variable:

```
File: 6.pov  Line: 21
File Context (5 lines):

union{
    #for
Parse Error: No matching } in 'union', undeclared identifier 'for' found instead
```

Any use of [`SolidFromFaceNormalPoints.inc`](https://github.com/watchduck/convex_polyhedra/blob/master/povray_includes/SolidFromFaceNormalPoints.inc) (e.g. in [`SolidFromFaceNormalPoints.pov`](https://github.com/watchduck/convex_polyhedra/blob/master/povray_includes/examples/SolidFromFaceNormalPoints.pov)) throws the following error:

```
File: /home/me/Povray/include/SolidFromFaceNormalPoints.inc  Line: 22
File Context (5 lines):
        #for (Index, 0, Len-1)
            PointCutter( Points[Index], Offset )
        #end
    }
Parse Error: Expected 'object or directive', } found instead
```

I do not see anything wrong in these files. And as I mentioned, they have worked before.

My version is 3.6.1. I am not sure, which version I have used before.

```
me@z3:~/Code/convex_polyhedra/2b_colors_png/finished_pov/8$ povray 6.pov 
Persistence of Vision(tm) Ray Tracer Version 3.6.1 (g++ 3.4.1 @
 i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Some files still work, e.g. [`PointCutter.pov`](https://github.com/watchduck/convex_polyhedra/blob/master/povray_includes/examples/PointCutter.pov).

[Here](https://github.com/watchduck/convex_polyhedra/tree/master/povray_includes#solidfromfacenormalpoints) is some documentation about the functions used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I installed version 3.7.

```
Persistence of Vision(tm) Ray Tracer Version 3.7.0.8.unofficial (g++ @
 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
This is an unofficial version compiled by:
 Dimitri John Ledkov <xnox@ubuntu.com> for Debian <www.debian.org>
```

It was quite a pain. These steps worked for me:

I found it in the Synaptic Package Manager.

[image]

The INI file was initially in `/usr/share/povray-3.7/ini/`,
but the console output complained about its absence in `/home/me/.povray/3.7`, so I moved it there.

I appended the folders for the default and my own include files:

```
Library_Path=/usr/share/povray-3.7/include/
Library_Path=/home/me/Povray/include/
```

It still complains, that there is no `povray.conf`, but I see no problem.